# How to merge jquery-UI slider with canvas rotate() method?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, html2canvas

I'm using a plugin called html2canvas and the plugin does not support css rotate.  I want an user to be able to rotate an image using a jQuery UI slider. I'm new to programing and I have no idea how to do this. Here is what I have so far?
http://jsfiddle.net/davadi/3d3wbpt7/3/

`

```
$("#slider").slider({
  value: 0,
  max: 360,
  min: 0,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#image").css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotateZ(' + ui.value + 'deg)',
    })}});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is too over powered to be used just to display images. What you want to do can simply be done by a simple `<img>` tag. I forked your jsFiddle and changed the canvas to just an image. It does what you want it to do 
http://jsfiddle.net/tphwzq3g/ I simply changed  `$("#image")` to  `$("#goo")`

Comment: thanks for your answer but the problem is that I have to add the html2canvas plugin and the plugin does not support css rotate. So I have to rotate the image before it reaches the canvas. Are you telling me that jquey UI slider can't be used on a canvas element?

Comment: It can be, It's just that you're trying to rotate something that doesn't exist in the DOM, you do not have an element with Id = "image". But if you want you can rotate your entire canvas like this. http://jsfiddle.net/kzsdzyd0/

Because elements inside the Canvas cannot be controller like normal HTML elements, that's why .css() will not work on it. it will only work on DOM elements.